# Fullscreen product view for eshop

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, image-gallery, zooming

**I am trying to find plugin or tutorial of product fullscreen view like on next sites:**

http://www.armaniexchange.com/product/cotton+trench+coat.do?sortby=

or

http://store-us.hugoboss.com/boss/partner-water-resistant-hooded-coat/hbna50238757,en_US,pd.html&cgid=22000#!i%3D0%26color%3D001_Black

**Maybe someone will provide me with a link?) Because I honestly didn't find anything usefull.**

Small addition:
What do I mean? On hugoboss website you can click "fullscreen view" below images or on armani site - "view larger". 
You will get to the fullscreen view. And I'm searching for something like this.

Thanks in advance.

BR,
Nick K.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly - you are looking for something like the following:

http://codecanyon.net/item/etalage/180719?ref=themespotters&ref=themespotters&clickthrough_id=119361192&redirect_back=true

**EDIT:**

In this case. On the product page I would probably add an absolutely positioned div which has a width and height of 100%;

```
.product-overlay {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

You could then use jquery to open and close this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#fullscreen').click(function() { //This is your "Full Screen" link
        $('.product-overlay').show();
    });

    $('.product-overlay #close').click(function() { // This is your close button
        $('.product-overlay').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Not exactly. I mean fullpage view. 
On hugoboss you can click "fullscreen view" below images.
On armani "view large".
And you will get to the fullscreen view. And I need something like this.

But still thanks for this link too. It will be usefull too.)

Comment: See the new edit. Should be more along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: Okay.
I will try to implement it. But as it should be like a small product gallery with several pictures of the product something like plugin can be very usefull for me as I wouldn't need to code thumbnails and so on.:)
BUt again, thank you for you suggestion.